# Issue with navbar background on different device sizes in developer console

Tags: html, css, navbar

Hii im new to web design, building my first website. But im having an issue with my header navbar, works fine in desktop, but when i shrink down in console, the background for the navbar stops stretching across the full width. Now i have not made the media queries yet for mobile and tablet versions, my question is, is my code flawed, hence why the navbar background does not stretch, or will i be able to fix that with a new media queries rules?

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-wrap">
               <nav class="navbar">
                   <div class="nav-logo">
                       <div id="logo">
                           <a href="index.html"></a>
                       </div>
                       <div id="site-name">
                           <h1>Trans-Atheist</h1>
                           <p>Ignorance Is Never Bliss</p>
                       </div>
    
                   </div>
                   <div class="nav-buttons">
                       <div class="button">
                          <a href="index.html" class="menu-item">Home</a>
                       </div>
                       <div class="button"> 
                          <a href="about.html" class="menu-item">About</a>
                       </div>
                       <div class="button">
                          <a href="videos.html" class="menu-item">Videos</a>
                       </div>   
     
    
                   </div>
    
               </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
      


        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="colunm1">
                    <div class="links">
                       <h1>Links</h1>
                       <a href="https://www.patreon.com/trans_atheist?fan_landing=true">
                        <img src="images/patreon.png" alt="this is a patreon image" width="260px" height="200px">
                       </a>

                       <a href="">
                           <img src="images/discord.png" alt="This is a discord link" width="260px" height="200px">
                       </a>

                       <a href="">
                           <img src="images/youtube.jpg" alt="This is a link to Youtube Channel" width="260px" height="200px">
                       </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="colunm2">
                    <div class="section">
                        <h1 class="centre">About me and what i do</h1>
                         <p class="centre">I am a Ex-jw content creator and activist. 
                            I make youtube videos, including rebuttals and debunking 
                            of teachings. My aim is to help as many people  as possible 
                            to leave and wake up from religious indoctrination.
                         </p>
                         <p class="centre">Hello, i am creating videos and podcasts, enlightening people to the destructive power of cults, i see myself and others like me as educators. I do not believe in money and power, but i do need to support myself while i do this work
                            Jehovahs Witnesses Have some very destructive teachings. I want to explore and pull apart at those teachings.</p>
                        
                         <p class="centre">It would mean the world to me if you were to support me on patreon, Please find the link to my patreon on the side bar to the left on desktop and the dropdown menu above for mobile. Please also see the links to my other content like discord server and youtube.</p>   


                         <div class="video">
                            <div id="last-vid" class="vid-indiv">
                                <h3>Ex-jw My sexual abuse, waking up, and disfellowshipping by Trans-Atheist</h3>
                                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9-EbGF-Obhg" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="colunm3">
                     <div class="ad-sec">
                         <h1>Ad Section</h1>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <p>Trans-Atheist</p>
                <p>Remember Ignorance Is Never Bliss</p>
                <p>Email: katysykes420@gmail.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>        
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

my css

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(61, 59, 59);
    width: 100%;
}

.container-header{
    background-color: rgba(84, 14, 150, 0.568);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;    

}


.nav-wrap{
    background-color: rgba(84, 14, 150, 0.568);
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%; 
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 40px;

}

.nav-logo{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#logo{
    background-image: url('/images/default.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px; 
    object-fit: contain;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.site-name h1{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.nav-buttons{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.button{
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    height: 42px;
}

.button a{
    color: gold;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.5s;
}

.button:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid gold;
}

.button a:hover{
    color: rgb(230, 215, 132);
}

h1, p, h3{
    color: gold;
}



.content{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
}

.colunm1, .colunm2, .colunm3{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.colunm1{
    border-right: 1px solid indigo ;
}

.colunm3{
    border-left: 1px solid indigo;
}

.centre{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align: center;
}

.links > a > img{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.vid-indiv{
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#last-vid{
    padding-bottom: 90px;
}

.footer{
    background-color: rgba(84, 14, 150, 0.568);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the Navbar but the video. As it has a fixed-width in the html the whole `.content` overflows when the screen shrinks.

In the future try commenting out different sections of your code at a time to find out where the problems are. I also like to use provisional colored borders on elements to see clearly how they behave.

Comment: Thank you i will give that a go, see if i can fix that, never thought that would have been the problem. And yea i will start using comments, i know its a little messy at the moment

Comment: Yea that has seemed to work by changing width to a percentage. Still has a problem below 500px screen size, but think that mostly because i need to stop using the grid for small devices and let the divs stack instead. so thank you very much that was very helpful